# OS X: g++ compiled program get bus error while clang compiled doesn't

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, clang, bus-error

I'm working on [Kevin Beason's smallpt](http://www.kevinbeason.com/smallpt/).

The program runs well with `clang-omp++ smallpt.cpp`.

But it doesn't goes well under `g++ -fopenmp smallpt.cpp`:

1. Duplicate warning (compiled successfully):

> /var/folders/j_/5w2s7bwx4zl9r_m976qpmpcc0000gn/T//ccEDNQ2r.s:612:11:
>   note: change section name to "__text"
>           .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
>                    ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /var/folders/j_/5w2s7bwx4zl9r_m976qpmpcc0000gn/T//ccEDNQ2r.s:1571:11:
>   warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated

2. `bus error` shuts down program every time I start:

> Rendering (4 super sample)  0.39%[1]    21811 bus error  ./smallpt

When I comment the core line (line `279`):

`SingleRay = SingleRay + radiance(SRay(Camera.m_Origin+RandDir * Scale, RandDir.normalize()), 0) * (1.0/SampleNum);`

Program finishes without `bus error` (and produce dark image).

I don't see any illegal memory access, what's wrong with it and how can I fix it (in `g++`)?

---

I replace `erand48()` to self-defined one. (might be irrelevant)

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-6
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/6.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-6 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 6.2.0 --without-multilib' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.0 (Homebrew gcc 6.2.0 --without-multilib)
```

Comment: May be a misconfiguration of your host computer. I just copied the pastebin posted, compiler locally and successfully ran the executable without a hitch - granted, the resulted file is seriously undersampled, but the binary run to completion. BTW: `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) 5.4.1 20160904`

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I think something's wrong with my `g++` (the warning I get is weird). I just add my `g++` detail.

Comment: My laptop's CPU is just getting orange cooling down from white hot after running the task with a `1024` cli arg. Definitely is something with your compiler/linker setup.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi My Ubuntu goes well... I guess I've messed the g++ lib/toolchain.